AWS launch template being replaced by EKS role
I have a launch template that I use for EKS.
This launch template includes a storage volume that is gp3 and resource tags (to make the billing clearer). Something I have recently noticed however is when I click "Update Now" on a node group via the EKS dashboard, this resets the storage volumes to gp2 and deletes all of my tags.
Is there a setting that would result in the volume type and resource tags not being updated? When I click "Update Now" all I'm expecting to be changed is the AMI.
Here is an example:
Version 12 (created by my user):
v12 storage
v12 resource tags
Version 13 (created by arn:aws:sts::____:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEKSNodegroup/EKS):
v13 storage
v13 resource tags

Recently I've observed the same behavior; the EKS service [role] is taking our launch template and creating a brand new one with different or additional attributes. Specifically I noticed that EKS is adding a security group to the launch template when we did not specify one originally.
We are deploying our resources with Terraform which may make a difference because sometimes the AWS Console tries to be helpful and overrides certain values or bundles multiple API calls together for convenience.
We were able to specify "gp3" in the block_device_mappings section of the launch template and the volumes were indeed deployed as gp3.
I would try 1) checking if your instance type is compatible with gp3 volumes and 2) deploying your resources via Terraform.
